# Meaning of Good fortune?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **Good fortune**.

Paragraph:

> Shortly after Mr. Darby received his degree from the “University of Hard Knocks,” and had decided to profit by his experience in the gold mining business, he had the **good fortune** to be present on an occasion that proved to him that “No” does not necessarily mean no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[fortune](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortune)** (n): 3a. prosperity attained partly through luck : SUCCESS  3b. luck

"Good fortune" implies that Darby was *lucky* to be at some event that would, eventually, lead him to some kind of *success* (in the gold mining business).  Another example:

> She had the good fortune to be born into a family with good political connections, which helped pave her way into public office.

"Good fortune" can also be a general *salutation*, meaning the same thing as "good luck".